Extra variant options (more than 3) on Shopify product page
I am trying to add more variant options on the Shopify product page, as Shopify only allows up to three options by default. I'm sending extra variant options (which have different prices) from the product page. When the customer selects any of these extra variants, the price is added to the total. I then send all the variant data (including extra variants) through properties to the cart page.
Once in the cart, the prices are adjusted using JavaScript, and the data is stored in an array successfully. When the customer clicks on checkout, a request is sent to my external endpoint to create a draft order. The customer is then redirected to checkout via the draft invoice URL. So far, this works fine.
The issue arises when I want to show the product image. To display it, I need to send the variant ID in the array. However, if I include the variant ID, I can't set a custom price because it picks the default variant's original price. On the other hand, if I don't send the variant ID and save it as a custom item, the image won't display, and Shopify's analytics won’t track the product data (e.g., which items were sold). Since it's treated as a custom item, this tracking fails.
Is there any way to achieve both: showing the image and having a custom price while retaining Shopify's product tracking?
Or, is there another way to achieve this functionality without using the draft order strategy?
